# How to merge nodes (when same value found in specific node) in single node

Tags: c#, xml

I want to merge nodes when same value found in  node and check value of  is it sequence wise or not

Please check below points:

1)If code-id tag value is sequence wise and subject tag value is same then merge the nodes.

2)If code-id tag value is sequence wise but subject tag value is diff then avoid merging.

3)If code-id tag value is not sequence wise but subject tag value is same then avoid merging.

4)If code-id tag value is not sequence wise but subject tag value is diff then avoid merging.

Can you please tell me how to get desired output?

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);
            XElement xElementSelectRoot = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//root");

            XElement xElementCreateRoot = new XElement(new XElement("root"));

            IEnumerable<XElement> lstOFCatogory = xElementSelectRoot.XPathSelectElements("//category").OrderBy(r => r.Value).ToList();

            foreach (var varXNodeCategory in lstOFCatogory)
            {
                if (varXNodeCategory.Parent.Name == "Product")
                {
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.LoadXml(varXNodeCategory.Parent.ToString());
                    XmlNodeList xmlNodeCategoryList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//category");

                    XmlDocument xmlDoc1=new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc1.LoadXml(varXNodeCategory.ToString());

                    XmlNode xmlNodeSelectCategory = xmlDoc1.SelectSingleNode("//category");
                    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeCategoryList)
                    {
                        xmlNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xmlNode);
                        if (xmlNode.FirstChild.InnerText.Equals(xmlNodeSelectCategory.FirstChild.InnerText))
                        {
                            xmlNodeSelectCategory = xmlNode;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlDoc.LastChild.AppendChild(xmlNodeSelectCategory);
                    XmlNode xmlNode1 = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Product");

                    var varXElement= XElement.Parse(xmlDoc.InnerXml);

                    xElementCreateRoot.Add(varXElement);
                }
                else
                {
                    xElementCreateRoot.Add(varXNodeCategory);
                }
            }
```

.....................................................................................................................................................................
   Input:
.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
<root>
  <category>
    <code-id type="pub">e00001</code-id>
    <title>test334</title>
    <ranking>240</ranking>
  </category>
  <Product>
    <Product-subject-title>
      <subject>BIOLOGY ARTICLE</subject>
    </Product-subject-title>
    <category>
      <code-id type="pub">e00002</code-id>
      <title>test34</title>
      <ranking>160</ranking>
    </category>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product-subject-title>
      <subject>IN BRIEF</subject>
    </Product-subject-title>
    <category>
      <code-id type="pub">e00003</code-id>
      <title>test6</title>
      <ranking>117</ranking>
    </category>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product-subject-title>
      <subject>IN BRIEF</subject>
    </Product-subject-title>
    <category>
      <span>
        <code-id type="pub">e00004</code-id>
      </span>
      <title>test3</title>
      <ranking>52</ranking>
    </category>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product-subject-title>
      <subject>BIOLOGY ARTICLE</subject>
    </Product-subject-title>
    <category>
      <code-id type="pub">e00005</code-id>
      <title>test28</title>
      <ranking>10</ranking>
    </category>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product-subject-title>
      <subject>IN BRIEF</subject>
    </Product-subject-title>
    <category>
      <code-id type="pub">e00006</code-id>
      <title>test4</title>
      <ranking>116</ranking>
    </category>
  </Product>
  <category>
    <span>
      <code-id type="pub">e00007</code-id>
    </span>
    <title>test76</title>
    <ranking>14</ranking>
  </category>
</root>
```

.....................................................................................................................................................................
   My output will look like this:
.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
<root>
  <category>
    <code-id type="pub">e00001</code-id>
    <title>test334</title>
    <ranking>240</ranking>
  </category>
  <Product>
    <Product-subject-title>
      <subject>BIOLOGY ARTICLE</subject>
    </Product-subject-title>
    <category>
      <code-id type="pub">e00002</code-id>
      <title>test34</title>
      <ranking>160</ranking>
    </category>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product-subject-title>
      <subject>IN BRIEF</subject>
    </Product-subject-title>
    <category>
      <code-id type="pub">e00003</code-id>
      <title>test6</title>
      <ranking>117</ranking>
    </category>
    <category>
      <span>
        <code-id type="pub">e00004</code-id>
      </span>
      <title>test3</title>
      <ranking>52</ranking>
    </category>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product-subject-title>
      <subject>BIOLOGY ARTICLE</subject>
    </Product-subject-title>
    <category>
      <code-id type="pub">e00005</code-id>
      <title>test28</title>
      <ranking>10</ranking>
    </category>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product-subject-title>
      <subject>IN BRIEF</subject>
    </Product-subject-title>
    <category>
      <code-id type="pub">e00006</code-id>
      <title>test4</title>
      <ranking>116</ranking>
    </category>
  </Product>
  <category>
    <span>
      <code-id type="pub">e00007</code-id>
    </span>
    <title>test76</title>
    <ranking>14</ranking>
  </category>
</root>
```

Comment: 1) the link is broken. 2) you really sould include some examples in XML format to explain your situation -> if looks like *this XML example* transform to *this XML example*. It makes the life easier of the people who are willing to help you. Which also increases the willingness ;)

Comment: please check above example and tell me how to fixed it

Comment: how are you parsing the xml? using XMLReader ?

Comment: please check above code with example

Comment: You destroyed valuable edits to your question twice by now... relevant parts of text are missing because you don't use code markup (\`<code-id>\`) in your description. Please fix it yourself since you rejected help from others.

Comment: I am confused, the input and output example differs only in `Product` entry. I am sorry, but I cannot deduce the cases from this example

Comment: @MongZhu look in the markup code, it makes much more sense with all the invisible text ;)

Comment: hi please check and tell me how to get desired output

Comment: you please check input and output format,you will definitely understand what i want...I already sorting tag through code-id value i just want to merge tag when subject tag value is same and please maintain sequence also using code id value

Answer (score 0):

I got solution and its working fine now.

```
        XDocument xmlDocNew = XDocument.Parse(xElementCreateRoot.ToString());
        XElement xElementSelectRootNew = xmlDocNew.XPathSelectElement("//root");
        XElement xElementCreateRootNew = new XElement(new XElement("root"));
        IEnumerable<XElement> lstOFCatogoryNew = xElementSelectRootNew.XPathSelectElements("//category").OrderBy(r => r.Value).ToList();
        List<Class1> lstClass1 = new List<Class1>();
        int intClassIndexCounter = 0;
        foreach (var x in lstOFCatogoryNew)
        {
            if (x.Parent.Name.ToString() == "Product")
            {
                if (lstClass1.Count() > 0)
                {
                    if (lstClass1[lstClass1.Count()-1].SujectName.Trim().ToString() == ((XElement)x.Parent.FirstNode).Value.Trim().ToString())
                    {

                        var xsDoc = new XDocument(new XElement(XElement.Parse(x.Parent.ToString())));

                        XElement xElementSelectProduct = xsDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Product");

                        xElementCreateRootNew.Elements("Product").Last().Add(xElementSelectProduct.XPathSelectElement("//category"));


                        lstClass1.Add(new Class1(((XElement)x.Parent.FirstNode).Value.Trim().ToString(),//subject title
                            ((XElement)x.FirstNode).Value.Trim().ToString(),//code-id
                            x.Parent.ToString().Trim()));//product set

                        intClassIndexCounter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xElementCreateRootNew.Add(x.Parent);
                        lstClass1.Add(new Class1(((XElement)x.Parent.FirstNode).Value.Trim().ToString(),//subject title
                            ((XElement)x.FirstNode).Value.Trim().ToString(),//code-id
                            x.Parent.ToString().Trim()));//product set

                        intClassIndexCounter++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    xElementCreateRootNew.Add(x.Parent);
                    lstClass1.Add(new Class1(((XElement)x.Parent.FirstNode).Value.Trim().ToString(),//subject title
                        ((XElement)x.FirstNode).Value.Trim().ToString(),//code-id
                        x.Parent.ToString().Trim()));//product set

                    intClassIndexCounter++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                xElementCreateRootNew.Add(x);
            }
        }
```